# How to cross compile a rust project with openssl?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, grpc

My project is written in Rust (`Ubuntu 16.04, CMake 3.5.1`).

Previously it used `grpcio = "0.4.0"` as a dependency in `Cargo.toml` and I could successfully cross-compile (i.e., create a static binary) it (using `cross`). However, after I changed my dependency to `grpcio = { version = "0.4.2", features = ["openssl"] }` I can't cross-compile it anymore: it says that it couldn't compile `grpcio-sys = "0.4.2"` and displays a few CMake errors (and I can't continue to use `0.4.0` because it doesn't support `features=["openssl"]`):

1. Couldn't find some enviroments flags for OpenSSL (even though I installed `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`) for `Ubuntu 16.04`.
2. `gRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER is "module" but PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR is wrong`.

How can I fix it? [This](https://www.andrew-thorburn.com/cross-compiling-a-simple-rust-web-app/#openssl) post says I should avoid OpenSSL completely. And here's another [post](http://timryan.org/2018/07/27/cross-compiling-linux-binaries-from-macos.html) about cross compiling with OpenSSL.

Comment: Just adding my comment that there needs to be a better solution for this

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find, but I believe nowadays there's an easy option for OpenSSL cross-compilation - enabling the [`vendored` feature](https://docs.rs/openssl/#vendored).

This causes OpenSSL to be compiled from source as part of your project's build (and therefore against the same target architecture as the rest of the project) instead of expecting it to already be installed on your system.

You can propagate the feature into your own project to optionally depend on `vendored` by adding something like this to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[features]
...

# If compiling on a system without OpenSSL installed, or cross-compiling for a different
# architecture, enable this feature to compile OpenSSL as part of the build.
# See https://docs.rs/openssl/#vendored for more.
static_ssl = ['openssl/vendored']

[dependencies]
...

[dependencies.openssl]
optional = true
version = ...
```

Enabling the `static_ssl` feature when building your project will then compile OpenSSL at the same time.

For `grpcio` in particular see [their documentation](https://crates.io/crates/grpcio#feature-openssl-and-openssl-vendored), which indicates they provide an [`openssl-vendored` feature](https://github.com/tikv/grpc-rs/blob/b9ddf27/grpc-sys/Cargo.toml#L59) for this purpose. So you can add `grpcio = { version = "0.7", features = ["openssl-vendored"] }` to your `Cargo.toml` to unconditionally compile OpenSSL, or use the same pattern as above (just don't mark the `grpcio` package as `optional`).

[This post](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross/issues/229#issuecomment-597898074) goes into some more details about different ways of compiling with OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a similar problem when trying to compile to Turris Omnia router (armv71). I found a great docker image that solved my problem.

Take a look at: https://github.com/messense/rust-musl-cross.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cross-compile your rust program with every feature of **Openssl**, because some version of OpenSSL doesn't support (feature as Vendored) which helps for cross-compilation. So you can use that version of OpenSSL which supports this feature. like openssl = { version = "0.10", features = ["vendored"] }

Answer (score 0):

The posts that you shared are correct: you have to avoid OpenSSL in Rust. Not because OpenSSL is bad *per se*, but because the current port in Rust is actually relying on *your system's* OpenSSL installation. Therefore it is not suitable for cross-compilation.

Instead, you need a more portable solution, such as `rustls`, which is supported by `reqwest` and several other web-oriented crates.

In your case [`grpcio`](https://docs.rs/grpcio/latest/grpcio/index.html), it seems that the default feature set makes you use `boringssl` instead of your system's OpenSSL, which should be good for you.